# CentOS 6: Not Allowing Connection to Port 5432

Tags: postgresql, port, firewall

I have a CentOS 6 as VM on a Windows box. I can use Putty to connect to the machine (on port 22) but can't connect via client applications (pgAdmin) or via `telnet mytargetvmip 5432` to the postgresql (I did modify the pg_hba.conf file).

Here is what I have done:  I changed the ip tables file and then do a `service iptables restart` command but to no good.

Please note, in the given iptables file, I had also tried `iptables -I INPUT 1 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT` just before COMMIT but no luck. I want to be able to connect via any remote IP.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
 COMMIT
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, in addition to pg_hba.conf file, I also had to modify the `postgresql.conf` file to uncomment and make the `listen_address` to `"*"`. After that, I removed my entry for port 5432 from the iptables file and then the following commands:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT 
service iptables save 
service iptables restart
```

Everything works.
HTH